# I made a little beginner java "math" but don't know where the mistake is

Tags: java, math

I have made these codes just for fun to train a little bit since i'm a 15 year old beginner in java but don't know where the problem is and what to put after the "lol" method
thank you for the help

```
public class mathClass {

    static int a = 10;
    static int b = 15;
    static int c = 22;
    static int result = 0;
    static double counter = 0.25;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double resultone;
        double resulttwo;
        double resultthree;
        double resultfour;
        double resultfive;

        resultone = a + b;
        resulttwo = a + c;
        resultthree = a * c;
        resultfour = b / c;
        resultfive = b % a;

        lala(resultone);
        lala(resulttwo);
        lala(resultthree);
        lala(resultfour);
        lala(resultfive);
    }

    public static void lala(double output) {
        result++;
        System.out.println("result " + result + " is " + output);
    }

    public static void  lol() {
        while(counter < 10){
            counter++;
            int number = 0;
            number++;
            System.out.println("Counter "+ number + " is " + counter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I don't know what the problem is either. Why? You *didn't say what the problem was* :(

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what is going wrong?

Comment: I am trying to configure the "lol" method to print the  ("Counter "+ number + " is " + counter) sorry for not explaining it right

Comment: @gs2rom out of curiosity, what do you think it will print?

Comment: Please use function/method names which at least make a minimal attempt at describing what the function/method is supposed to do, especially if you might ask someone to help you. On top of that, commenting your code is important! It just kind of makes sense.

Comment: @gs2rom I don't see anywhere you are calling your `lol` method.

Comment: What should it print? @Zéychin auto formatting wouldn't hurt either

Comment: i want it to print Counter 1 is 1.25 counter 2 is 2.25 ....

Comment: _I am trying to configure the "lol" method to print..._: for that you need to call `lol` method from your `main` **OR** `lala`method as you called your `lala` from main.

Comment: @smit How can i do that? sorry still a beginner

Comment: check the answer I posted below.

Comment: @gs2rom just put `lol();` in your main method or in `lala` method and see what happens. Then configure your output as your needed.

Comment: It worked i just called the lol() method in the main method..thank you everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want to also get the lol method text

If you are trying to have it output 10 lines

```
public static void  lol() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       counter++;
       System.out.println("Counter "+ i + " is " + counter);
    }
}
```

Next add:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     lol();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that division is not giving results as expected

instead of

```
static int a = 10;
static int b = 15;
static int c = 22;
static int result = 0;
```

use

```
static double a = 10.0;
static double b = 15.0;
static double c = 22.0;
static double result = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a closing curly bracket `}` after the `lol()` method. There is one missing at the end. That bracket will close the class and resolve the compilation error.

Comment: This could be a copy-paste error

Comment: all i am getting is result 1 is 25.0
result 2 is 32.0
result 3 is 220.0
result 4 is 0.0
result 5 is 5.0 while i want to also get the lol method text

Answer (score 2):

Along with the missing brace, you never call `lol()` in your main method. If it isn't being called, how would it run?

Answer (score 1):

`resultfour = b / c;`

Dividing an int by an int gives you an int as a result. In this case, 15 / 22 = 0, since 0 is the largest int value less than or equal to 15.0 / 22.0.

Either make a,b,c,d doubles, or cast one of the values while doing the division...

`resultfour = (double)b / c;`

Comment: it tried making a b c doubles but didn't work

Comment: In that case, you're going to have to better describe what you're expecting the output to be.